# argparse error with parsing required arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a script saved as workspace.py

```
import argparse
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('title', type=str, help="Will be displayed as the title")
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--folder', help='Point to the folder you want to read from (defaults to current folder in command prompt)', type=str, default=os.getcwd())
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    someFunction(args.folder, args.title)
```

Which I call from terminal with:

```
workspace.py myTitle
```

Resulting in the error

> workspace.py: error: the following arguments are required: title

I have no idea why this is happening because I supply "myTitle" in the terminal. If I specify a `default=` for the title argument it works perfectly with that value. The part that is throwing me is it doesn't even get to the `print(args)` so I cannot see what the program thinks is what, but instead fails at `args = parser.parse_args()`

I tried to even redo the exact example at: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#introducing-positional-arguments (copied below)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("echo", help="echo the string you use here")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.echo
```

Running

```
workspace.py hello
```

Results in (after adding parenthesis to the print for 3.X)

> workspace.py: error: the following arguments are required: echo

Is there something I'm missing? Why does it not just print "hello"? Is there some Python 3 specific syntax I'm missing or something?

Comment: How are you executing the script? With both `python workspace.py myTitle` and `./workspace.py myTitle`, it works on my machine (™).

Comment: You could add, at the start, `import sys` and `print(sys.argv)`.  This shows us what the parser has to work with.  Also, what OS?  WIndows by any chance?

Comment: @hpaulj I just did that and `workspace.py hello` results in `['C:\\Users\\me\\folder\\subfolder\\workspace.py']` Shouldn't there be a second item in this list of "hello"? I'm on Windows 10

Comment: Windows command window requires (or at least required) some special handling to pass arguments on through when using `batch` and `shebang` notation.  But my memory of that dates way back to 3.2 :(  https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#arguments-in-shebang-lines

Comment: What does `ftype | findstr -i python` output in your (*cmd*) terminal?

Comment: @CristiFati `'-i' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: No way! Just the string as I posted, copy / pasted in the console, no dblquotes, nothing else? Or maybe written by hand? Anyway it's hard to believe. What about `ftype | findstr "ython"`? Are there some special settings on your terminal?

Comment: @CristiFati Hmm I guess I had a type because a straight copy/paste got me 
 
`C:\Users\rparkhurst>ftype | findstr -i python`;
`Python.ArchiveFile="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*`;
`Python.CompiledFile="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*`;
`Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*`;
`Python.NoConArchiveFile="C:\Windows\pyw.exe" "%L" %*`;
`Python.NoConFile="C:\Windows\pyw.exe" "%L" %*`

Comment: Those are *"%L"*s? I have *"%1"*s instead but on my machine both versions work fine. So are you sure you typed the script name correctly in your *cmd* (like in the error you got when you typed the command that I first sent)? Also `print args.echo` would raise a *SyntaxError*. What happens if you execute in the console `ftype Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%1" %*` and then run your script?

Comment: @CristiFati `Access is denied.`;
`Error occurred while processing: Python.File.`. I've posted an answer that should work for me. Apparently including `python` every time the function is called (while tedious and seemingly avoidable) allows the program to run correctly

Comment: Yes, because your user is not an administrator. You could also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008516/how-do-i-set-default-app-for-a-file-extension-to-an-exe-on-windows-10-after/52009412#52009412.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten it to work if I run `python workspace.py someString` instead of `workspace.py someString`. I do not understand why this version works, since command prompt obviously recognizes it as Python and runs it correctly until `args = parser.parse_args()`. **There were no errors** like `'workspace.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` There was no problem importing modules either. Consider the below command prompt session if you are running into a similar error. Maybe you will simply have to include `python` in your commands like I have to...

```
C:\Users\rparkhurst\PycharmProjects\Workspace>workspace.py MyTitle
usage: workspace.py [-h] [-f FOLDER] title
workspace.py: error: the following arguments are required: title

C:\Users\rparkhurst\PycharmProjects\Workspace>python workspace.py MyTitle
Namespace(folder='C:\\Users\\rparkhurst\\PycharmProjects\\Workspace', title='MyTitle')
```