# Different python used in .cmd when file is ran vs. when python is opened directly

Tags: python, path

On Windows 10:

Hi, I am having an issue with understanding how my computer works with python. When I run a python file in my IDE, Atom, it uses the python from PATH. When I run python in .cmd, it uses the python from PATH. When I execute the same python file from .cmd it uses a python that is not in PATH. Why is it doing this and how can I get it to use the same python? I want everything to use the anaconda python.

I don't understand where the \AppData\ python is coming from?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[![
][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F1wA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F1wA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in *Control Panel* is just a template (if you will). Every  process gets those settings when it starts, but it can modify them afterwards. Take the following example:

1. Start *cmd.exe*:

   1.1. `echo %PATH%` - will output the inherited value

   1.2. `set PATH=%PATH%;some_other_dir` - will change the inherited value in the current (*cmd.exe*) process

   1.3. Repeat ***#1.1*** - will output the updated value

   1.4. Open the *Control Panel* settings again. You won't see *some_other_dir* there

To check the current *Python* process environment (inherited from the parent process), use *os.environ*. Add in your script:

```py
import os

print(os.environ["PATH"])
```

So, the non *Anaconda* *Python* might actually be in *%PATH%*.

But the behavior could also be (and I'm leaning towards this one) due to [[Wikipedia]: File association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_association). For more details, check [[SO]: How do I set “default App” for a file extension to an “.exe” on Windows 10 after April 2018 update (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52009412/4788546).