# Windows 11 - Associate .yaml file to Open With Default Application

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, yaml, windows-11

I'm trying to configure Windows 11 to associate a `.yaml` file to open with a default application (vscode). I have tried right-clicking my yaml file, `Open With` -> `Choose another app`, but there is no `Always use this app to open...` checkbox to select a default application.

[image]

I have seen other solutions suggest going to `settings` -> `apps` -> `default apps`, however the `.yaml` extension doesn't appear to be recognized (only .yml) when I navigate there.

[image]

How can I configure windows 11 to always open `.yaml` files with a default application other than Notepad?

Comment: [\[SO\]: How do I set "default App" for a file extension to an ".exe" on Windows 10 after April 2018 update (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52009412/4788546).

Answer (score 2):

### In VSCODE

#### Go to File: Preferences: Settings

[image]

### In the searchbar type file.associations

[image]

### Add the following associaton

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| *.yaml | yaml |

Comment: Bro, need way to configure this in Windows, not in vscode